# Discord.py How to avoid the first loop to trigger using discord.ext.tasks

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, discord.py, task

How do I prevent the first loop in my discord bot right after the start to trigger? The loop should happen every 30 minutes and I dont want it to trigger on the start of the bot.

```
from discord.ext import tasks

@tasks.loop(minutes=30) 
async def hunger():
    #Doesn't really matter what is here..


@hunger.before_loop
async def before():
    await client.wait_until_ready()

hunger.start()
client.run('xxx')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check with `current_loop` for the current iteration of the loop (note that this starts from 0)

```py
@tasks.loop(minutes=30) 
async def hunger():
    if hunger.current_loop != 0:
        #Doesn't really matter what is here..
```

#### Reference:

- [`Loop.current_loop`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks/index.html#discord.ext.tasks.Loop.current_loop)

Comment: Says local variable hunger not assigned :/

Comment: How have you named your function? The code above works flawlessly for me.

Comment: If you have it in a class @Bertos, you need self.func.current_loop